# Как реализовать кэширование в Windows Media Player?

Tags: c#, winforms, mediaplayer

Использую на форме media player, который проигрывает музыку напрямую с интернета. Но бывает что интернет немного тупит и воспроизведение музыки на несколько секунд останавливается. Можно ли как-то реализовать кэширование для 
музыки в windows media player?

И есть ли еще какой-то нормальный aydio player для Windows Form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите NAudio на http://naudio.codeplex.com, проигрывать музыку со стрима с буферизацией.